# Javascript: Why I can't clearTimeout in my object behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I have been solving this for many hours but I don't know why I can't solve it. I have the following code:

```
var Timer_Tick;
var Game_Engine = {
    //Set the min and sec of the timer by default is 2 min
    min:1,
    sec:60,
    star_count: 0,
    tongue_count: 0,
    time: '',
    star1: '',
    star2: '',
    star3: '',
    star_bar: '',
    tongue_bar: '',
    frog: '',
    bug: '',
    flower: '',
    Timer: function () {
        //Start Timer
        var that = this;
        var stop = function () { that.stopTimer(); };
        Timer_Tick = setTimeout(function () {
                var Time = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, that.min, that.sec--).toTimeString().slice(3,8);
                that.time.text = Time;
                console.log(that.min + ':' + that.sec);
                    if (that.min === 1 && that.sec === 40) {
                        that.bug.gotoAndPlay('take_photo');
                        that.flower.onPress = null;
                        stop();
                    }
                    else if (that.min === 1 && that.sec === -60) {
                        that.stopTimer();
                        //clearTimeout(Timer_Tick);
                        that.time.text = '00:00';
                        createjs.Tween.get(that.bug, { loop: false }).to({ y: that.bug.y + 100 }, 400, createjs.Ease.linear);
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            that.bug.gotoAndPlay('bite');
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                that.flower.gotoAndPlay('broken_flower');
                                that.frog.gotoAndPlay('lose');
                            }, 200);
                            createjs.Tween.get(that.bug, { loop: false }).wait(500).to({ x: 200, y: -100 }, 6000, createjs.Ease.linear);
                        }, 400);
                    }

                that.Timer();        
        }, 100);
    },
    stopTimer: function () {
        //Pause or stop Timer
        clearTimeout(Timer_Tick);
    }
};
```

I already put the `debugger` to find out that my event is fired or not. The result is it is fired correctly as expect but the Timer doesn't stop and keep going forever. Can anyone help me I really need your help now. I'm new to javascript :). Thanks in Advance.

Comment: +1 for indenting your code properly.

Comment: The only problem that I could see is the value in `Timer_Tick`. Alert the value when the timer is set and again in `stopTimer` to see that you are setting and getting the proper value.

Comment: I like to indent my code so that I can easily read it :)

Comment: I've found the answer anyway thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "return false;" after you call stop in your timer function. As it is now I think you will stop the Timer but then you will start it again at the bottom of the function.

```
if (that.min === 1 && that.sec === 40) {
   that.bug.gotoAndPlay('take_photo');
   that.flower.onPress = null;
   stop();
   return false;
}
```